# Error:(1297) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Material_Headline'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-styles

So I just updated my Android Studio along with my Windows laptop, after retrieving my project from github,I tried to run it and got this error. Now I'm not one to post without scavenging for the right answer on the internet. Most of the things I have tried didn't work out. So in this post I included my gradle screenshot, my styles screen shot and a screenshot of the problem plus one of my SDK manager. Thanks in advance for your help and lets create a fantastic day [image][image][image][image]

Comment: You dont have any Material_headline named Theme defined in values folder. its that simple

Comment: Adding a Matetial_headline named Theme doesn't work, it just deletes it and shows the same error